# Autofac FactoryScoped Linq to SQL data context

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, autofac

What does `FactoryScoped` registration with a Linq to SQL data context mean? Who takes care of the disposing?

Here is the code I saw. For an ASP.NET application, I assume `FactoryScoped` is not recommended for data contexts?

```
builder.Register(c => new MyDataContext("connectionString"))
       .As<MyDataContext>()
       .FactoryScoped();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FactoryScoped` in 1.x is renamed in 2.x to `InstancePerDependency`, which imo better describes the effect. It means that Autofac will serve up a new instance each time the service is injected. In your case a new data context will be created upon injection.

Autofac will still take care of disposing, but herein lies the pitfall. Every instance of `MyDataContext` will be tracked *in the current lifetime scope*, and will thus not be freed until the scope is freed.

To take control of disposal yourself you can tag the registration with `ExternallyOwned`. You could also look into the `Owned<>` type. Read up on [deterministic disposal](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) and [owned instances](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances).

Comment: A service that is registered `InstancePerDependency` can be disposed before the container. For example, in a web application, services that are registered IPD or per lifetime will be disposed at the end of the Http request. The key here is proper use of lifetime scopes. See http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope and http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ where the creator states "Don’t resolve from the root container. Always resolve from and then release a lifetime scope."

Comment: @Jim - you're right, I think of the lifetime scope as the "container", but I agree that the wording isn't right. Will correct it.

Comment: Interestingly, Autofac used to call them nested containers. When they got renamed to LifetimeScope But now I do when trying to explain it to another person.